# How to verify xml encoding

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse an XML file that was created internally at my company. The file is supposed to be UTF-16 encoded but I am getting an error with the Python script that I am writing (see below). I'm trying to figure out if the problem is with the file or my script. Is there a way to verify the encoding? All of my searches have ended in XML Validation tools or tools that check for well formed XML. I was hoping to try XMLSpy but I currently don't have access to it.

The code that is throwing the error is the 'parser.parse' line (Python 2.7):

```
from xml.sax import make_parser
from xml.sax.handler import ContentHandler
import codecs

parser = make_parser()
curHandler = XmlHandler()
parser.setContentHandler(curHandler)

parser.parse(codecs.open(infile, 'rb', fileEncoding))
```

where 'infile' is the XML file in question and 'fileEncoding' in this instance is 'UTF-16'.

The script works fine on UTF-8 encoded files. But with the UTF-16 files I am getting the following error:

```
xml.sax._exceptions.SAXParseException: XmlFile.xml:1:30: encoding specified in XML declaration is incorrect
```

I'm sorry but I can't post the XML. It is not complex but does contain words/names from multiple foreign countries. My current suspicion is that the encoding is UTF-8 but the encoding attribute is being set to UTF-16. Is there a way to verify this?

UPDATE:
Ok. So now I'm thoroughly confused. I changed the encoding on the XML file to UTF-8 instead of UTF-16 but forgot to change it on the script. The script ran as expected. So the file encoding='UTF-8' but opened with:

```
parser.parse(codecs.open(infile, 'rb', 'UTF-16'))
```

works as expected with no errors.

More Info: I am developing/executing in a Win7/Server 2008 environment.

Answer (score 2):

Get yourself a HEX editor (or write a program to dump the first eight bytes of the input file).

1. Look for a [Byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Representations_of_byte_order_marks_by_encoding) (BOM) at the very beginning. If it's there, that's your encoding.
2. Otherwise you should see `0x3C` (UTF-8), `0x003C` (UTF-16) or possibly, but unlikly, `0x0000003C` (UTF-32) (the opening `<` characterd of the XML prolog.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The BOM is showing FF FE so I'm assuming the encoding is UTF-16LE but I'm trying to find out if there is a way to verify that the file is encoded correctly?